# Javascript for loop only creates one child

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have an array of js objects, and for every object in array I am trying to create a div with a template, designated with `<template></template>`. I am trying to do this using a for loop. The for loop does exactly what I want, one time.

Here is my HTML template to be copied:

```
<template id="tracktemp">

  <div class="trackerItem">
    <div class="itemNameTextCont">
      <p class="itemNameText">Combatant Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHpTextCont">
      <p class="itemHpText">HP 100</p>
    </div>
    <div class="itemApTextCont">
      <p class="itemApText">AP 30</p>
    </div>
    <div class="itemActionButtonsCont">
      <div class="actionButtonCont"><button class="actionButton">Heal</button></div>
      <div class="actionButtonCont"><button class="actionButton">Dam</button></div>
      <div class="actionButtonCont"><button class="actionButton">Stat</button></div>
      <div class="actionButtonCont"><button class="actionButton">Abil</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemModifyButtonsCont">
      <div class="modifyButtonCont"><button class="modifyButton">Edit</button></div>
      <div class="modifyButtonCont"><button class="modifyButton">Remove</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>
```

The HTML Section it's being copied into (within trackerCont)

```
  <section class="trackerModule">
    <div class="trackerModuleCont">
      <div class="trackerHeaderCont">
        <h2 class="trackerHeader">Combatants</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="trackerTopButtonsCont">
        <div class="topButtonCont"><button class="topButton">Add</button></div>
        <div class="topButtonCont"><button class="topButton">Add From</button></div>
      </div>
      <div id="trackerCont" class="trackerCont">

        
      </div>
      <div class="trackerBottomButtonsCont">
        <div class="bottomButtonCont"></div>
        <div class="bottomButtonCont"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

And the JS doing the copying

```
var trackerArray = [
    {Name: "Joe Brown", HP: 100, AP: 30},
    {Name: "Steve Smith", HP: 100, AP: 30},
    {Name: "Jane", HP: 100, AP: 30}
]

function buildTracker() {
    var trackerLength = trackerArray.length;
    var trackItemTemp = document.getElementById('tracktemp').content.cloneNode(true);

    for (i = 0; i < trackerLength; i++) {
        var combatant = trackerArray[i];
        var itemParent = document.getElementById('trackerCont');
        trackItemTemp.querySelector('.itemNameText').innerText = combatant.Name;
        trackItemTemp.querySelector('.itemHpText').innerText = combatant.HP;
        trackItemTemp.querySelector('.itemApText').innerText = combatant.AP;
        document.createElement(trackItemTemp);
    }
        
}
```

I understand to some extent that appendChild can only create one element. I should be using document.createElement instead, no? I do not understand how to go about rewriting the code to copy the HTML template using createElement... If someone could lend me a hand that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

```
document.createElement(trackItemTemp);
```

To

```
document.getElementById("trackerCont").appendChild(trackItemTemp);
```

---

(edit)
I missed whole function code and i also missed there was a variable itemParent so I edited the last line of the function. Make sure to use cloneNode in each loop.

```
function buildTracker() {
        var trackerLength = trackerArray.length;
        var trackItem;
        for (i = 0; i < trackerLength; i++) {
            var trackItemTemp = document.getElementById('tracktemp').content.cloneNode(true);
            var combatant = trackerArray[i];
            var itemParent = document.getElementById('trackerCont');
            trackItemTemp.querySelector('.itemNameText').innerText = combatant.Name;
            trackItemTemp.querySelector('.itemHpText').innerText = combatant.HP;
            trackItemTemp.querySelector('.itemApText').innerText = combatant.AP;
            itemParent.appendChild(trackItemTemp);
        }   
    }
```